# Apache sending incorrect response header for .js files

Tags: javascript, apache, mime-types, content-type

I noticed that Chrome is reporting the wrong MIME type for .js files.    The files are served with Apache 2, which originally did not reference js files in its conf file.

I added the following configuration to http.conf:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

Then reloaded the config.  .js files are still being sent with this Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 16:39:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.10
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

There are no .htaccess files.

What would cause Apache to send an incorrect Content-Type, even though I've specified application/x-javascript in the config and reloaded the server?

Comment: It looks like this header was sent by PHP interpreter (according to `X-Powered-By` property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this on another server recently and solved the problem.  `conf.d/php.conf` contained these lines:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .phtml .html .css .js
AddType text/html .php
```

I changed the first line to

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .phtml .html
AddType text/html .php
```

Then saved and restarted Apache.  The js & css files now appear with the correct mime type in Firefox/Chrome.

*As an aside I tried adding `AddType text/javascript .js` just below `AddType text/html .php`, but the files still showed as `text/html` in Inspector.  I had to remove .css and .js from AddHandler for the correct mime type to be sent.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` in your httpd.conf then you should place it into `<FilesMatch \.php$> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>` to let Apache send the good Content-Type for others files.